# how to edit a specific post slug using a php code?

Tags: php, posts, permalinks

I want a php code by which i can show a modified link to the post.
when using

```
<?php get_post_permalink(); ?>
```

it shows e.g.: (www.mysite.com/post-name-one).
what i need is something like (www.mysite.com/abstract/post-name-one).
because adding this word to the link will activate a function to change the post template.
I tried to use:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">Abstract</a>
```

but this shows the original link and i couldn't edit it. 
so i tried to use:

```
<a href="<?php get_site_url(); ?>/abstract/%post-name%" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">Abstract</a>
```

but it didn't work.
I think there must be a way to add "abstract" to the link after

```
<?php get_site_url(); ?>
```

and before the post name
but i couldn't figure it out.
Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this 
`$post_id = 11;
 $post = get_post($post_id);
 $slug = $post->post_name;
 <a href="<?php get_site_url(); ?>/abstract/<?php echo $slug; ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">Abstract</a>`